# Qt Json Error: Undefined Symbols Architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, macos, qt-creator

I am trying to network response application in Qt creating using Json API in C++. I am currently using a MacBook running on Monterrey. Every time I run an application or open a new project, I get these errors:

```
:-1: error: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Widget::set(QJsonObject)", referenced from:
      Widget::qt_static_metacall(QObject*, QMetaObject::Call, int, void**) in moc_widget.o

:-1: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [json-requests.app/Contents/MacOS/json-requests] Error 1**
```

I've updated all the necessary command line tools and even did a fresh install of Qt Creator and have tried troubleshooting/cleaning my code and same issue pops up.

Send help, thank you!

Tried revising code and clean project folders, error still populates

Comment: Please show a [mre], at a guess you've not defined `Widget::set`

Comment: I had a set function in my widget.h that I hadn't defined in my widget.cpp as I wasn't using it anymore so getting rid of that fixed it, thank you!